# waf at linking time: "undefined reference" error

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, undefined-reference, waf

So I've been banging my head on this compiler error for the last 2 hours and thought I would post the code here to see if anyone can shed any light on my mistake.

I have stripped out all the irrelevant bits to leave a bare minimal program (shown below) which as far as I can see should compile and run. If I comme but I can't see what is wrongnt out the call to testFunc in main then everything compiles and runs fine. With the call to testFunc in however, I get the following:

```
$ ./waf -v --run abr-tool
Waf: Entering directory `/home/conor/workspace/msc/AdaptiveIPTV/Software/conor/ns3/ns-3.15/build'
[1665/1822] cxxprogram: build/src/abr-tools/examples/abr-tool.cc.4.o -> build/src/abr-tools/ns3.15-abr-tool-debug
19:04:19 runner ['/usr/bin/g++', '-L/usr/lib', '-lboost_iostreams', '-L/usr/lib', '-lboost_iostreams', '-pthread', 'src/abr-tools/examples/abr-tool.cc.4.o', '-o', '/home/conor/workspace/msc/AdaptiveIPTV/Software/conor/ns3/ns-3.15/build/src/abr-tools/ns3.15-abr-tool-debug', '-Wl,-Bstatic', '-Wl,-Bdynamic', '-Wl,--no-as-needed', '-L.', '-L.', '-L.', '-L.', '-L.', '-L.', '-lns3.15-point-to-point-debug', '-lns3.15-internet-debug', '-lns3.15-mpi-debug', '-lns3.15-bridge-debug', '-lns3.15-network-debug', '-lns3.15-core-debug', '-lrt']
src/abr-tools/examples/abr-tool.cc.4.o: In function `main':
/home/conor/workspace/msc/AdaptiveIPTV/Software/conor/ns3/ns-3.15/build/../src/abr-tools/examples/abr-tool.cc:7: undefined reference to `testFunc()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

As you can see the code below is being built as part of a much larger project, and I am aware that the error may be coming from that build process rather than an issue with my code, but either way I have hit something of a wall in my understanding of what is happening here. I'm learning c++ as I go and to tell the truth I don't feel experienced enough to even just compile this code on its own and be able to say "that should definitely work but it doesn't", which is why I present it like this.

Another couple of points which might be relevant:

- I can use macros defined in abr-helper.h from abr-tools.cc, and the problem persists when I put abr-tools.cc in the same folder as abr-helper.h and just use '#include "abr-helper.h"'.
- the original error was the same thing, but for a bunch of other stuff defined in abr-helper.h and use in abr-tools.cc

I would appreciate any help you folks can offer, thanks in advance.

abr-helper.h:

```
#ifndef ABR_HELPER_H
#define ABR_HELPER_H
#include <iostream>

void testFunc();

#endif /* ABR_HELPER_H */
```

abr-helper.cc:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "abr-helper.h"

void testFunc(){
        std::cout << "this is all testFunc() does ..." << std::endl;
}
```

abr-tool.cc:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ns3/abr-helper.h"

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){

    std::cout << "in main()" << std::endl;
    testFunc();
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Even if it's a waf error, and not a code error, thank you a lot for your effort to reduce the code to a minimal example!

Answer (score 5):

It appears the file `abr-helper.cc` doesn't get compiled. You can easily test this by adding a

```
#error "Test"
```

line to that file. If the build succeeds, the file isn't getting compiled and you need to add it. How you do that depends on your compiler or IDE.

Comment: I got it, thanks. abr-helper.cc was being compiled, but not linked when abr-tool.cc was compiled. It was configuration issue with the build tool.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include abr-helper.cc in your compilation, otherwise the implementation is not linked in.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know waf, so I won't be able to give a solution. But here is what happens :

During compilation, everything works fine. The problem occurs during the linking (ld error).

On the line starting with : 19:04:19 runner, there is no reference to abr-helper.o or something like that. You must have forgotten to add abr-helper.cc somewhere in your waf configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to the other answers (I also don't see the file `abr-tool.cc` to be compiled), the function `void testFunc` needs to be declared `extern`.

Comment: thanks, I read that it is only required for data and not functions. Is there still some issue with reliability if it isn't used, or just for correctness?

Comment: It is, but I have made it a habit to always write it. First it is valuable documentation and there is one case, when move the declaration of a former static function into a header it will catch if you forgot to remove the static from the definition. So I should probably take back the "needs" and substitute it with a "should".